# Synonym for “hold on to”

Tags: synonyms

I want to say “This institution encourages its students to hold onto their passions”

I felt like “hold onto” sounds odd. I mean the institution lets students keep their passions and doesn’t force them to give them up. Any advice,

Comment: Hold onto your hat!

Comment: No worries.  “Hold onto your passions” is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/hold_onto.html

Comment: Are you asking about the distinction between “hold onto” and “hold on to” (with “onto” split into 2 words)?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively  *embrace*; *[hold on to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-on-to-onto)* is good though too.

> She ***[embraces](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/collocations/british/embrace#:%7E:text=embrace%20collocations%20and%20examples%20%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8C&text=fully%20or%20enthusiastically%3A%20actively%2C%20eagerly,and%20in%20particular%20the%20internet.)*** diversity, and believes that all students should have an opportunity to contribute to music lessons.

According to Macmillan Dictionary, the most common collocations with *ebrace* are:

challenge, change, concept, diversity, ethos, idea, innovation, notion, opportunity, principle, technology

> You should ***hold on to*** her, she's too good to lose to a competitor.
> <sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

Comment: You should explain why you think embrace is the  best option.

Comment: *embrace* connotes to me a beginning – “Before I embraced Fooism, I was a Bazist” – while the desired sense is about not-ending.

Comment: Embraced is good if you want a positive word, but the question seems more like "we don't want to actively destroy your dreams".

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use **hold on to** as to maintain or sustain the quality of the *student's* passion, you might want to consider **uphold**

> This institution encourages its students to **uphold** their passions

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uphold#:%7E:text=Etymology,%E2%80%9Cuphold%2C%20support%E2%80%9D) describes this word as:

> To keep erect; to support; to sustain; to keep from falling

List of other alternatives:

- maintain
- sustain (if the 'institution' wants to assist the increase of the student's passion)
- preserve
- affirm (if the 'institution' wishes to support the student emotionally)

Comment: I would *uphold* an impersonal principle, but applying that to an interior passion feels strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

"Pursue" would be a good fit here. It evokes both a sense of not giving up, and advancing one's interest in an area.

"The institution encourages its students to pursue their passions."